# How to change the text of QLineEdit while QTableWidget is being updating with data?

Tags: qt, qtablewidget, qlineedit

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGBHX.jpg)I'm creating a Qt application in which there is a `QTableWidget` and a `QLineEdit`. The `QTableWidget` is updated by a thread with lots of data and it takes time.While the `QTableWidget` is being updated `QLineEdit` becomes disable, unfortunately. Means user cannot change the text in `QLineEdit` until the `QTableWidgit` is updated. So, my question is that, is there a way with which user can change the text while the `QTableWidget` is being updated.

this is the mainwindow screenshot. Maybe because the mainwindow is a single thread that's why `Qtablewidget` is disabling every other thing.

Comment: this is impossible to answer with so little info. What may happen is that your QTableWidget generate too many events due to the number of insert. why do you manipulate a widget from a thread is beyond me.

Comment: i have added the screenshot of the mainwindow

Comment: maybe because the mainwindow is a single thread that's why qtablewidget is disabling every other widget while it is being updated.

Comment: what we need is code. at least the connections to QTableWidget, The amount of data in terms of rows and columns, the time it takes before your *complete ui* becomes responsible.

Answer (score 0):

without the source code is hard to tell, but simply:

> QTableWidget does not disables QLineEdit

It's your code that's disabling the QLineEdit, not Qt. simply put:

> Do not disable QLineEdit when the QTableWidget is beign updated.

Comment: i have added the screenshot of the mainwindow

Comment: the screenshoot doesn't tells me anything about *your own code*

Comment: I know I'm not disabling QLineEdit. maybe because the mainwindow is a single thread that's why qtablewidget is disabling every other widget while it is being updated.

Comment: So, if there is a way to put a widget in a different thread and then update that perhaps can work.

Comment: qtablewidget doesn't disables anything, your *code* could run for so long when running the model update that the screen is not updating.